# columns are not evenly distributed over the list rows

Tags: android

i am displaying a list view with a custom row. sometimes the text is longer, then the rows are not displaying properly. meaning that the columns (0,1) of different rows are having different width. I want to fix the width of columns into ratio of 3:1 but doesn't seem to work. below is code for row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Shoppers Stop"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="whitefield, bangalore"
                android:textColor="#ffababab" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="here is the subtitle" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:numStars="5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="enter" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: @Geobits wonderful, plz post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `layout_weight`, you should zero out the corresponding width/height.

For your example, use `layout_width="0dp"` for both weighted `LinearLayout` elements.

[Linear Layout Weight Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) - See the sidebar and example code.